# react-i18next - do I access deeply nested dynamic keys using the t function

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I am translating a react application using i18next and I wanted to know if there was a way to access nested dynamic keys like `roles[RACE_DRIVER]?.title` using t() function.
The ENTranslation.js file that contains my translation is like this

```
// ENTranslation.js

roles: {
    [RACE_DRIVER]: {
      title: 'Race driver',
      titleShort: 'Driver',
      description: 'This is a driver description'
    },
    [TEAM_MANAGER]: {
      title: 'Team manager',
      titleShort: 'Manager',
      description: 'This is a team description'
    },
}
```

and my config is

```
// i18n.js

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: ENTranslation
  },
  de: {
    translation: DETranslation
  },
};
i18next
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    debug: true,
  });

export default i18next;
```

I am expecting t(roles[RACE_DRIVER]?.title) to return 'Race driver' but it doesnt. How do I handle it please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keys wrap quotes
first Example:-

```js
const keys = ["RACE_DRIVER","TEAM_MANAGER"];
const roles = {
    [keys[0]]: {
      title: 'Race driver',
      titleShort: 'Driver',
      description: 'This is a driver description'
    },
    [keys[1]]: {
      title: 'Team manager',
      titleShort: 'Manager',
      description: 'This is a team description'
    }
 }
 console.log(roles["RACE_DRIVER"]?.title)
```

Second Example:-

```js
const roles = {
    ["RACE_DRIVER"]: {
      title: 'Race driver',
      titleShort: 'Driver',
      description: 'This is a driver description'
    },
    ["TEAM_MANAGER"]: {
      title: 'Team manager',
      titleShort: 'Manager',
      description: 'This is a team description'
    }
 }
 console.log(roles["RACE_DRIVER"]?.title)
```

```js
    const Race_Driver = "RACE_DRIVER"
    const TEAM_MANAGER = "TEAM_MANAGER"
    const roles = {
        [Race_Driver]: {
          title: 'Race driver',
          titleShort: 'Driver',
          description: 'This is a driver description'
        },
        [TEAM_MANAGER]: {
          title: 'Team manager',
          titleShort: 'Manager',
          description: 'This is a team description'
        }
     }
     //console.log(roles["RACE_DRIVER"]?.title)
              
      console.log(roles.RACE_DRIVER?.title)
```

Comment: Thanks @gagan I am exporting the keys from another file like so:


`export const RACE_DRIVER = 'RACE_DRIVER';`
`export const TEAM_MANAGER = 'TEAM_MANAGER';`

Comment: @UmehChiamaka so just call :-  roles.RACE_DRIVER?.title  OR roles["RACE_DRIVER"]?.title

Comment: when I wrap it in t(roles["RACE_DRIVER"]?.title) it doesnt work